# Do we say "If you don't obey your teachers, they ask you to face the wall or a wall" when we talk about it in general?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, articles, phrase-choice

This often happens in some Asian countries where children need to obey their teachers at school.

Now, you are talking to your child in general and you are not talking about a specific school or a specific wall.

If I applied English grammar rule, I would say

"**If you don't obey your teachers, they ask you to face a wall**" because we are not talking about **any specific wall**.

But "**face a wall**" sounds pretty strange to me.

But If I say "**If you don't obey your teachers, they ask you to face *the* wall**", then it may break some grammar rules because people may ask "**what specific wall are you talking about?**"

Comment: Well in this case, it will be pretty obvious that you will be talking about the wall somewhere in the school (like right outside the class). Yeah but again, it comes from colloquial language and understanding of the same. Any otherwise, it would be considered as wrong, or like you said 'breaking some grammar rules'.

Comment: I think the English equivalent would be 'being made to stand in the corner'. (I don't know whether this still happens in schools, but I believe there is still a concept of making an unruly child spend a few minutes alone and quiet.) The definite article implies _one of the corners of the classroom_.

Comment: @KateBunting That depends on the teacher, like how my 4th-grade teacher did that but my others didn't beside kindergarten. But my 4th-grade teacher treated us as if we were her children. But it does still happen in schools, mainly primary school.